# DBeaver Community Edition - No Driver for Apache Cassandra on Mac

Tags: macos, cassandra, dbeaver

I am a Mac user attempting to set up DBeaver to connect to Cassandra DB.  https://downloads.datastax.com/#odbc-jdbc-drivers has no Mac version for Apache Cassandra to download.  Any solutions or alternative Cassandra DB tools available for Mac devices?

Installed DBeaver Community Edition.  But no Cassandra driver comes with it.

Answer (score 7):

You can totally leverage the [ING JDBC Cassandra driver](https://github.com/ing-bank/cassandra-jdbc-wrapper) to plug DBeaver on a Cassandra node.

#### Step by Step instructions

**1. Start Cassandra Locally**

> Assuming you are running Cassandra locally with Docker
>
> ```
> docker run --name cassandra \
> -p 9042:9042 \
> -d cassandra:4.1.3
> ```

**2. Setup Cassandra**

After about 30s, Cassandra should be started. To connect with DBeaver and the Cassandra JDBC you need to provide the keyspace so let us create one named `stackoverflow`

- Access the cqlsh console:

```
docker exec -it cassandra bash -c "cqlsh"
```

- Get your datacenter name (default is `datacenter1`) it will also be needed in the JDBC url.

```
select data_center from system.local;
```

- Create a few things : keyspace and table

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS stackoverflow 
WITH REPLICATION = { 
  'class':'SimpleStrategy', 
  'replication_factor':1
 };
use stackoverflow;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries (code TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO countries(code, name) VALUES('fr', 'France');
INSERT INTO countries(code, name) VALUES('uk', 'United Kingdom');
INSERT INTO countries(code, name) VALUES('usa', 'United States');
select * from countries;
```

**3. Download DBeaver**

Go the [DBeaver download page](https://dbeaver.io/download/) or [Dbearver lite](https://dbeaver.com/download/lite/) and pick the proper DMG either your are on intel or apple silicon (M1, M2)
[image]

**4. Download the JDBC driver**

- Go the release [github page of ING JDBC Driver](https://github.com/ing-bank/cassandra-jdbc-wrapper/releases)
- Pick the latest release. in `Assets`, downloads the file `cassandra-jdbc-wrapper-x.Y.Z-bundle.jar` in your `Documents` folder.

**5. Create DBeaver Driver**

- Open DBeaver application
- In the menu go `Database > Driver manager`
- The Panel Click `new` without selecting anything

[image]

- There, choose the TAB `libraries` and select `Add File`, look for the jar we just downloaded.

[image]

- Go back to the tab `Settings` and enter the following values:

| Var | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Driver Name | cassandra-ing-driver |
| Driver Type | generic |
| ClassName | `com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver` |

[image]

- Save your modifications with `[OK]`

**6. Create the Datasource**

- In the menu now select `Database > New Database Collection`
- Pick the driver `cassandra-ing`

[image]

- Populate the URL as follow:

```
jdbc:cassandra://127.0.0.1:9042/stackoverflow?localdatacenter=datacenter1
```

- Click `Test Connection`

[image]

- Validate and Save
- On the left panel you can now see your data

[image]

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to install this driver on Macbook Pro (Mac OS Monterey)?

Comment: Will edit my response then