# Trouble Connecting DBeaver to Cassandra in Docker Container on Debian 12

Tags: docker, cassandra, debian, dbeaver

I am facing a problem when trying to establish a connection between DBeaver Community and a Cassandra database that is running inside a Docker container on Debian 12. I have followed all the instructions provided in this excellent tutorial ["DBeaver-community-edition no driver for Apache Cassandra on Mac"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100407/dbeaver-community-edition-no-driver-for-apache-cassandra-on-mac/77762813#77762813) from @clunven, but when I run the 'test connection' step, I encounter the following error message:

[image: Cassandra Driver Config on DBeaver]

[image: Cassandra Java Driver install on DBeaver]

[image: DBeaver Cassandra Connection settings]

[image: Cassandra Test Connection Error on DBeaver]

Comment: Can you add the docker.file or the command line run which shows you exposed port 9042 external to the container

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the error message and any relevant application source code in plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your suggestion, I was able to resolve the issue connecting DBeaver to Cassandra running in a Docker container. The key was in the port mapping, which wasn't set up correctly.

When I ran docker ps, I noticed that the CQL port 9042/tcp was listed but without any host port mapping – it didn't show the expected 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp. This meant that while the port was exposed within the Docker network, it wasn't accessible from my local machine.

Based on your recommendation, I stopped and removed the existing container and then ran a new container with the correct port mapping using the command:

```
docker stop cassandra-testing
docker rm cassandra-testing
docker run --name cassandra-testing -p 9042:9042 -d bitnami/cassandra:latest
```

After this simple change, I was able to successfully connect to Cassandra through DBeaver using localhost as the host and 9042 as the port. Your insight was invaluable, and I appreciate your help!

[image: Test "Connected"]